# Finding keywords in text and appending keyword topic

Tags: r, text, merge

I have a large data frame of text that i want to find keywords in.  The keywords also have categories applied to them.  I need help figuring out how to append 2 columns, 1 with the keywords found and 1 with the associated categories

I think i have the correct code to get the keywords column created; however, I can't figure out how to also create the category column.

```
#Generate sample data
text <- tibble(phrases = c("Hello my name is Bob", "I wasted time when I was that age", "What time is the party?"))
keys    <- tibble(words = c("name","age","time"),categories = c("demographic","demographic","details"))

#Find keyword matches
text_match <- sapply(paste0(keys$words), grepl, text$phrases) %>% 
              as_tibble() %>% 
              mutate(Keywords = apply(., 1, function(x) paste(colnames(.)[x == 1], collapse = " | ")))
```

This generates the keyword column correctly:

```
  name  age   time  Keywords                     
1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE name         
2 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  age | time
3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  time
```

But how can i create the category column.  I would want something like this:

```
  name  age   time  Keywords   Category                           
1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE name       demographic          
2 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  age | time demographic | details
3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  time       details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use `tidytext` as well as `tidyr` you can get to your exact output. But depending on how many keywords you have, you might want to stop at step1 below.

First I add an id to the text tibble. Then unnest this data into df1 with `unnest_tokens`. Merge this data with the keywords in step0. In step1 collapse the keywords and categories per id. In step2 add a TRUE column for each found keyword in step0 and spread this data and merge it with the result of step1 to give you the output you required.

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyr)

text <- text %>% mutate(id = row_number())
df1 <- unnest_tokens(text, "words", input = phrases)

step0 <- df1 %>% inner_join(keys)
# Joining, by = "words"

step1 <- step0 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Keywords = paste(words ,collapse = " | "),
            Category = paste(categories, collapse = " | "))

step1
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id Keywords   Category             
  <int> <chr>      <chr>                
1     1 name       demographic          
2     2 time | age details | demographic
3     3 time       details  

step2 <- step0 %>% 
  mutate(value = TRUE) %>% 
  select(id, words, value) %>% 
  spread(words, value = value, fill = FALSE) %>% 
  inner_join(step1)

# Joining, by = "id"

step2
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id age   name  time  Keywords   Category             
  <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>      <chr>                
1     1 FALSE TRUE  FALSE name       demographic          
2     2 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  time | age details | demographic
3     3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  time       details
```

Comment: perfect answer!  I have experience with Tidytext and it didn't even cross my mind to use it.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use case_when from dplyr if your list of keywords isn't very big.  i.e.:

```
text_match$category <- case_when(text_match$keywords== "name" ~ "demographic"
```

yields:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  age   time  Keywords   category   
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>      <chr>      
1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE name       demographic
2 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  age | time NA         
3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  time       NA
```

Comment: thank you for response.  unfortunately the list of keywords is rather large (+150 entries).  Also, could "case_when" work when there are multiple keywords as in the 2nd case above (age | time)?

Comment: phiver's answer probably will get you where you need to be, but just in case you end up using case_when in the future yes you can do multiples for each case.  you can use & for multiple matches across columns, or comma separate as well for multiple or's.